# Gradle Build single module

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have a problem with build single module from Gradle multimodule project.
I have a structure:

```
-root-project:
   -first-module
   -second-module
   -modules:
      -first-submodule
      -second-submodule
```

**setting.gradle.kts**

```
rootProject.name = "root"

include(
   "first-module",
   "second-module",
   "modules",
   "modules/first-submodule",
   "modules/second-submodule"
)
```

When I run ***./gradlew clean build***, each module builds.
When I run ***./gradlew first-module:clean first-module:build***, builds only first-module.
But when I run ***./gradlew modules:first-submodules:clean modules:first-build***, I got error:

```
* What went wrong:
Project 'first-submodules' not found in project ':modules'.
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

typo in module name? "first-submodule**s**" should not have trailing **s**

Comment: then flag it as a typo :) flag -> needs improvement -> community-specific reason -> typo (yes, it's incredibly undiscoverable, I know)